# Working in 3x3 arrays in Javascript and EaselJS, what is the best way to offset a chunked tile map?

Tags: javascript, easeljs

I am constructing a chunked tilemap system, using 3x3 mini-map chunks out of a much larger map. At this point I've got it working with the chunks but I can't quite figure out how to offset the tiles within the tile class, so that it fills them out relative to the original x/y of the object. It currently iterates with a nested for loop, but only displays one tile - in the top-left corner of each object. This is what I currently have:

```
(function() {

var tile = function(array, _x, _y, spritesheet) {
  this.initialize(array, _x, _y, spritesheet);
}
tile.prototype = new createjs.Container();

tile.prototype.Container_initialize = this.initialize;
tile.prototype.initialize = function(array, _x, _y, spritesheet) {

    this.x = _x * 120;
    this.y = _y * 120;

    this.tileArray = array; 

    this.tilesheet = spritesheet;

    this.i = 0;

    for (this.x = 0; this.x < 3; this.x++)
    {
        for (this.y = 0; this.y < 3; this.y++)
        {
            var tileSprite = new createjs.Sprite(this.tilesheet, this.tileArray[this.x][this.y]);
            tileSprite.x = this.x; 
            tileSprite.y = this.y;


            this.addChild(tileSprite);



            this.i++;
        }       
    }
}

window.tile = tile;
}());
```

Can anyone offer a suggestion on how to fix the offsets properly so all nine tiles are drawn out, not just one?

Comment: First of all, you are using x and y as iteration variables. You better use other variables, since you're using x and y to place your tiles if I'm not mistaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach to lay out a Grid is to do a single iteration with some math for placement.

Here is some pseudo-code (not tested, but should give you an idea of what you want)

```
var cols = 3;
var rows = 3;
for (var i = 0; i<rows*cols; i++) {

    // Determine the row & column using simple math
    var row = Math.floor(i/cols);
    var col = i%cols;

    // Create the item
    var tileSprite = new createjs.Sprite(this.tilesheet, this.tileArray[row][col]);
    // Note there is probably a better way to determine the item you want, you can probably
    // use the "i" variable instead.
    var tileSprite = new createjs.Sprite(this.tilesheet, i);

    // Position it using width/height variables
    tileSprite.x = col * COL_WIDTH;
    tileSprite.y = row * ROW_HEIGHT;
    this.addChild(tileSprite);
}
```

Comment: Definitely faster! Although it's still loading the wrong order overall, but that's a whole unique problem.